# Create And Delete Cookies Not quite working?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to create my one custom Validation class, for logging users in and out. however.
When i log out, the Verafy Bool does not return false. (The cookie is not deleted)

What am i doing wrong? And is there anything i should be doing differently?

Hope you can help!

```
    public static class Security
{

    private static HttpCookie cookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["Login"];


    //Tells weather you are logged in or not
    public static bool Verafy {
        get
        {
            if (cookie != null)
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }
    }

    //Removes cookie, (doesn't work!)
    public static void signOut()
    {
        cookie = new HttpCookie("Login");
        cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
    }

    //Creates a cookie for x days.
    public static void SignIn(int Days)
    {

        cookie = new HttpCookie("Login");
        cookie.Name = "Login";
        cookie.Expires.AddDays(Days);
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
    }


    //This is just temporarily..
    public static bool VerafyUser(string Username, string Password)
    {
        if (Username == "123" && Password == "123")
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you capture the request / response in Fiddler and post it up here?

Comment: BTW, there is no such word "Verafy"

Comment: Well, the word "weather" does exist ... doesn't make that much sense in this context though. Try "whether" instead.

Comment: I must have a better vocabulary than you guys xD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have taken the wrong approach here by storing a static variable for your cookie. As you never set the reference to null your property will never return false.

Get rid of the static field and have your property actually check if the cookie exists e.g.

```
public bool LoggedIn
{
    get { return HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["Login"] != null; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, will try to make everything non static, and see how that turns out, I dont really understand why this wont work... yet!

Comment: You can keep the class static as you can use the Login/Logout function across all users. However, the reason why it isn't working at the minute is when you log in, you set the static variable cookie to the value of a new Cookie. Then when you log out, you set it again with a new cookie therefore it never gets set to null hence it always appears as though the user is logged in. Also as it's static, if another user logs in they will reset the value - so in summary it's not a good approach. The fix is just to attempt to retrieve the cookie again and verify whether it exists or not.

Comment: I have a couple of qustion to that :)

You say that i set the static variable cookie to the value of a new Cookie? - Why is it a new Cookie, i'm a bit confused by this. Also. In order to set a cookie to null what must i do diffrent in my signout?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7678134/cookies-why-wont-this-work

Problem continues

Comment: "cookie = new HttpCookie('Login')" in both your Login/Logout functions is why your static variable will never go to null. Adding a new cookie with an expiration date of -1d will remove that particular cookie from disk, however, as your holding a reference to it (your static field) it will never be null as you never set it to be null, does that make sense? So I re-iterate I would say your current approach is wrong and you need to attempt to retrieve the cookie from disk to check if it exists or not (like my code above).

Comment: To answer your other question, you can't modify cookies using Request, you have to use Response therefore "Step 2" will never actually apply the changes to the cookie. As a rule of thumb when you want to GET cookies use Request, if you want to MODIFY cookies use Response. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa289495(v=vs.71).aspx for more info on using cookies.

Comment: Thank you James! Will give it another try today.

Answer (score 1):

You have static field for cookie here, so it will be shared between all users of your app, dude! If someone else logged in after you leave the app, cookie will be restored.

Read the article http://mikehadlow.blogspot.com/2008/03/forms-authentication-with-mvc-framework.html. Should help.