# Cookies. Why wont this work?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

i am lost, now the most simple things wont work for me.

Okay, so if i run this script with only Step1 - It will returns "NotNull" - good!

If i then run it With only Step 2 it would as expected return "Null" - good!

But if i then remove Both Step 1 AND 2 (After removing the cookie with step2)
It switches back to "NotNull" - Baad!

How can that be? How can i check if a cookie is Null !?

Hope you can help :)

```
        //Step 1
        HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Add(new HttpCookie("test") { Name = "test", Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(2) });

        //Stem 2
        HttpContext.Request.Cookies["test"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-2);
        HttpContext.Request.Cookies.Remove("test");
        HttpContext.Request.Cookies.Clear();


        string test = "Null";

        if (HttpContext.Request.Cookies["test"] != null)
        {
            test = "NotNull";
        }

        return Content(test);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the second step you are trying to modify cookies but you still working with `Request` object. To submit your modifications you need `Response` object. So, after your 2nd step cookies still alive.

```
    //Stem 2
    HttpContext.Response.Cookies["test"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-2);
    HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Remove("test");
    HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Clear();
```

Comment: Sorry, It did not work. If i use Response in step2 instead it never returns Null.

Comment: Are you invoking step 2 and checking in a single postback? If so - it will not work, because you didn't change the browser cookies collection.

Answer (score 0):

Clearing the cookie from the `Request` and `Response` won't remove the cookie from the client.  To truly remove the cookie, you need to set the cookie's expiration to a date in the past and re-add it to the response so that it will expire on the client:

```
if (Request.Cookies["test"] != null)
{
    HttpCookie test = new HttpCookie("test");
    test.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1d);
    Response.Cookies.Add(test);
}
```

Or, simply:

```
HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Add(new HttpCookie("test") { Name = "test", Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1d) });
```

Comment: Okay, that make sense, but it still doesnt work :/ It wont be Null. After executing your code, it still executes "NotNull"

Comment: After removing the cookie per my example, does it print "NotNull" on a subsequent request?